# why isn't my preg_match case insensitive?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

My form allows people to upload a file for 3d printing but I want to restrict possible files to .obj or .stl

```
} elseif (!preg_match("/^.*\.(stl|obj)$/i",$model['name'])) {
//reject because it's not the correct extension.
```

when the extension is lower case (.stl) the form works fine, but when it's uppercase (.STL) it rejects it

Comment: Please show `var_dump($mode['name'])` when this happens.

Comment: It works for me. There must be something else rejecting the upload. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c4eeaad716d663834965255c9d29d1040fae0b3e

Comment: Barmar your comment showed me what I was doing wrong. I forgot that I had not moved things into the $model array at this point in my code.

Answer (score 0):

It was a stupid human trick. It didn't work either way. Barmar's comment helped me look and see I had my variable name wrong.